# Text Template file can't find System.Core.dll

Tags: t4

I have a text template file that is designed to read through my database and build models from there, which has been working perfectly for 2 years, but all of a sudden today it cannot find System.Core.dll unless I explicitly state out the location.

This works:

```
<#@ template language="C#v3.5" #>
<#@ assembly name="C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Core.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc" #>
```

This doesn't work:

```
<#@ template language="C#v3.5" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc" #>
```

Obviously I don't want to have the path explictly stated as this may need to be different on a different developers machine. The only change that has been made to my system lately is that I ran the last month of Windows Updates (Windows 7).

Comment: I am still having issues with this problem, if anyone out there is able to assist it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to switch to a new machine and this is working just fine again. I don't know exactly what was happening, but the developer that had the machine that I was using before I did had gigs of bloat ware on it that may have caused the path not to be found.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the line

```
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
```

instead of

```
<#@ assembly name="System.Core.dll" #>
```

Comment: I tried this as well and it still didn't fix the issue. Thank you for your response though.

Comment: This fixed it for me!
The example in the documentation is wrong then: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586946.aspx#Anchor_0
"System.Xml.dll"